# Nikon sdk c# wrapper-capture live pics

Tags: c#

I am using Nikon D5200 camera to capture photo from using Windows application. For this I am using Nikon SDK c# Wrapper. I have downloaded the MD3 file Type0009.md3 with NIKON D5200 SDK.
But I don't know where to place the MD3 file. I am getting error **LoadLibrary failed to load MD3 file: Type0009.md3** . Can anyone suggest me what to do in this case?

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: Did you get any further? If so. how? I've got a similar issue with my D300.

Comment: Yes, You will have to download the appropriate md3 file from nikon site. With that you will get NkdPTP.dll. place this dll and md3 file in folder where your exe lives and you will get it done :)

Answer (score 1):

the md3 is sitting in the sdk /module / binary filfolder, move it to your project directory (not the debug or release) and it will work

Answer (score 0):

make sure you got the right md3 file, it should be in the same folder as your exe (\debug or \release under VS), but you need also copy the NkdPTP.dll (come with the sdk)  to the folder too.